# PDO utf8 is not working

Tags: php, pdo, utf-8

My utf-8 is not working in php with pdo. when i store België 
i have in my db België in my index page of html 
i have  `<meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />`

and in my php page i have

I have tried this but this isn't working

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES utf8"));
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

When i load the data from the db into a table then i have again the right value België. 
But with geocoder when i took a longer value like Jan Breydelstadion, Koning Leopold III-laan, Brugge, België then i get a error Zerro_results.

But when i change the word 
Jan Breydelstadion, Koning Leopold III-laan, Brugge, België to
Jan Breydelstadion, Koning Leopold III-laan, Brugge, België in my mysql

then my geocoder error is gone.

Comment: Are the tables encoded in `utf-8`?

Comment: @Cyclone he wrote, that in DB is item stored correctly

Comment: @pes502 - That was not my question, I asked what the encoding of the table is.

Comment: in my tables i have charset set utf-8   and collation utf-8_general_ci

Comment: You may need to add a PHP header, `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and *verify* that the tables and databases are set to utf8 charset (collation != charset) by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName`. And like the answer below suggested, specify the charset in the DNS in your PDO-object too.

Comment: i have also tried with a header but same result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to also add the charset to your connection string? As this :

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$username,$password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES utf8"));
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: same problem i have tried it now with mùnchen and in my db i found M&ugrave;nchen